# Maven compiler plugin complains of "No SLF4J providers were found"

Tags: java, maven, slf4j, maven-compiler-plugin

I am getting this message when building a single project:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ cli-helper ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /tmp/cli-helper/target/classes
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.


<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>11</source>
              <target>11</target>
              <compilerArguments>
                <endorseddirs>/tmp/cli-helper/target/endorsed</endorseddirs>
              </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>11</source>
              <target>11</target>
              <compilerArguments>
                <endorseddirs>/tmp/cli-helper/target/endorsed</endorseddirs>
              </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>/tmp/cli-helper/target/endorsed</endorseddirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

All of the other projects build fine - I cannot seem to spot the difference.  I have tried configuring the maven compiler plugin for just this project and manually including slf4j-simple as a dependency in it, but that didn't help either.

This project gets built into an executable jar with the dependencies copied into a lib directory in target.  As part of that profile, it includes slf4j-simple as a build dependency, not a plugin dependency.

Also, as another aside, I am using lombok and aspectj on this project.

Lastly, the other projects which are working appear to mirror this configuration, so they get built into an executable jar, leverage lombok and aspectj.

I can share my effective pom if that'll help, but there isn't anything more to it than what I stated above.

Comment: slf4j is only a facade. You need an implementation of a logging framework. The info message says that there is no logging framework to  which slf4j can forward the log messages. You will need something like log4j for doing the real work.

Comment: Yes, completely understood - I indicated that I included slf4j-simple in the plugin's dependencies (which I did not have to do in any other projects); however, that still didn't resolve the problem.  Again, what is causing this project to have that warning and no other project I have has that issue (even without adding that dependency to the plugin itself).

Comment: maybe the version of slf4j-simple is not compatible. You should use the same version as for slf4j-api. There are differences between 1.8 and pre-1.8 versions.

Comment: Is this a configuration you have done by hand or is this `mvn help:effective-pom` output?

Comment: The configuration above is a stripped-down version of help:effective-pom.

Comment: @Walter were you able to fix this? I have also added sl4j-simple on top of adding sl4j-api in my build.gradle, but its still complaining.